# Drupal 7: How do I get module config settings on to theme file?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am creating a new module. I have an admin panel where I set settings. In my `.module` file I can retrieve these settings using `$config = variable_get('mymodule_settings', []);`.

I am using `hook_theme()` to declare a theme:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function fcl_trustpilot_theme() {
  return [
    'mymodule_wrapper' => [
      'template' => 'theme/mymodule-wrapper',
      'variables' => [],
    ]
}
```

But how do I get the data from `mymodule_settings` to appear in the `theme/mymodule-wrapper` file?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's preferable to decouple your settings from the theme. The theme user (i.e. the code that calls your theme) should load the configs and inject to the template through variables.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return [
    'mymodule_wrapper' => [
      'template' => 'theme/mymodule-wrapper',
      'variables' => [
        'foo' => NULL,
      ],
    ];
}
```

```php
/**
 * Some other module implemented this hook_menu callback for a random path.
 */
function othermodule_random_endpoint() {
  $config = variable_get('mymodule_settings', []);
  return [
    '#theme' => 'mymodule_wrapper',
    '#foo' => $config['foo'] ?? NULL,
  ]
}
```

But if you really need to load the variable directly to your template file, there are 2 approaches:

### Loading Settings in Theme File Direct

All theme files in Drupal 7 are php files (as suggested by the suffix `.tpl.php`). I don't recommend it, but you can totally do this. In your theme file:

```php
<?php

// load the configs here
$config = variable_get('mymodule_settings', []);

?>

<div>
  <p>Hello, this is a config value: <?php echo $config['foo']; ?></p>
</div>
```

This is ugly but effective.

### Using the hook_preprocess_HOOK

The 2nd approach is to implement [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7.x).

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return [
    'mymodule_wrapper' => [
      'template' => 'theme/mymodule-wrapper',
      'variables' => [
        'foo' => NULL,
      ],
    ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_mymodule_wrapper(&$variables) {
  if (!isset($variables['config'])) {
    $config = variable_get('mymodule_settings', []);
    $variables['foo'] = $config['foo'] ?? NULL;
  }
}
```